# I have a problem in the config of URI of flask_sqlachemy db

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to create a register database with flask and sqlalchemy. This is my **app.py** code:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for, Markup
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
import os

from __init__ import app
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///users.db"

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    plan = db.Column(db.String(100))
    logosnumber = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, name, email, password, plan, logosnumber):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode('utf-8')
        self.plan = plan
        self.logosnumber = logosnumber
        db.create_all()


@app.route('/')
def first():
    return redirect(url_for('home'))

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/logo_maker')
def logo_maker():
    return render_template('logo_maker.html')

@app.route('/subscription')
def subscription():
    return render_template('subscriptions.html')

@app.route('/register', methods=["POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = Markup.escape(request.form['name'])
        email = Markup.escape(request.form['email'])
        password = Markup.escape(request.form['password'])
        plan = ""
        logosnumber = 0
        new_user = User(name, email, password, plan, logosnumber)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        return 'User registered successfully.'
    return render_template('register.html')

@app.route('/login')
def login():

    return render_template('login.html')        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And this is my `__init__.py` code (I use it just to configure secret key and get app variable):

```
from flask import Flask
from utilities import generate_secret_key
import threading
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)


def update_secret_key():
    global current_secret_key
    current_secret_key = generate_secret_key()
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = current_secret_key
    threading.Timer(60, update_secret_key).start()

current_secret_key = generate_secret_key()
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = current_secret_key
update_secret_key()
```

I have tried many solutions to make this code and database work but it still outputs the same error:

```
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set.
```

I used sqlachemy_database_uri and it shows me this error many times.

Comment: i find the error. i put the URI between app varibale and db. thanks